# Link with 2 variables in 1 variable

Tags: php, url

I want to find out what the filessize of this file is filesize().

With an echo it works:

$Data[textfile]; = Complete Filename with ending in Database

```
echo 'http://myurl.com/files/'.$Data[id].'/'.$Data[textFile].'';
```

But it doesn´t work like this:

```
$file = "http://myurl.com/files/" . $Data[id] . "/" . $Data[textFile] . "";
```

The link looks/should look like this:

http://myurl.com/files/123/textfile.docx

edit: sorry for my weird english...i hope the point is clear

Edit 2: I want to get the filesize of a pdf or docx

The rest of the code:

```
$size = filesize($file);
$size = $size/1048576;
$size = round($size,2);
echo $size." Mb";
```

Comment: Do I get you right and you want to receive the filesize of the url, or is something wrong with the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$file = 'http://myurl.com/files/' . $Data['id'] . '/' . $Data['textFile'];`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$file = 'http://myurl.com/files/' . $Data[id] . '/' . $Data[textFile];
```

Answer (score 1):

try `$file = 'http://myurl.com/files/'.$Data[id].'/'.$Data[textFile];`